# Arch Linux: installing grep from source

Tags: grep, arch-linux, make

I completely removed grep along with my package manager (Pacman) , on accident. Recovering form this issue would be easy but, I can't install grep. I downloaded the tarball and extracted it, but when I run `./configure` it gets ready then tells me it requires grep (outputs: `./configure: line 2613: grep: command not found`) how can I install grep, if it need grep? Any idea what to do?

Edit: I don't have busybox, I'm tying to replace dbus with dbus-x11 but it's only in the aur so I can't install it using pacstrap. So I have to have dbus installed but it breaks dbus-x11. I need dbus-x11 for well x11 support, I want to use deepin de (dde) but it needs dbus with x11.

I may have to completely switch to deepin os, which is apt based. I would really like to stay with arch as it's just so better, I love the rolling release type build.

Thx for any help

Comment: Does your system have `busybox` installed? I wonder if that can get you out of a jam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall the missing packages from a live distribution (e.g. via [USB flash drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media)) using the **pacstrap** script after [mounting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_systems#Mount_a_file_system) the partitions and setting up your [network](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration).

```
pacstrap /mnt grep pacman
```

To get you started you can follow the [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Install_essential_packages). If you are unsure what you have already deleted you can also reinstall the [`base`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/base/) package.

Comment: That should work thx, I was able to download the iso via links and mount dd it to a open partition as I don't have a USB, hopefully I can install just grep, as pacamn Installs dbus and I need to install dbus-x11. Thx for the help